# When to register to push notification in ionic

Tags: push-notification, ionic-framework

I am implementing ionic push notification to my app.

I want to know when shall I identify and register user. Is that should be done once for all (when first boot of the app), or I need to request for registration each time I start the application, so I refresh user's tokens ?